# Should I create custom page template or use functions.php?

Tags: wordpress, genesis

I'm using the Genesis framework for WordPress and the Business Pro theme.

I want to customise the contact page and if you view the URL below, you can see the Email and Telephone sections that I want to create next to the form.

My question is should I create custom page template or use functions.php to target the contact page using a conditional. I guess I'm trying to find out best practise or if one method is better than the other in this case.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I guess it's a matter of preference. Using a custom template would be the logical choice for _me_ as it would be more flexible than trying to customize things via `functions.php`.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter how you create a contact form and add it to the page.

You can use a contact form in a page template. It is easier to manage than managing one function in functions.php file having a lot of functions in it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option - is if you use "Genesis framework", use it further.

Otherwise, the part of the site with the framework and other through the code via ftp...

Make a page with this framework, there create what you need.

It will be easier to maintaining a site in the future. Especially if you make a website for a client who is unfamiliar with development.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I used a custom page template which did the job!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Genesis Simple sidebars plugin to create a custom sidebar which only displays on the contact page and populate that widget area with your email and telephone details.

No need for a template but if you want to, create a file named contact.php in your child theme folder and add the following code to the file :

```
<?php


// Template Name: Contact



genesis();
```

You can then select the Template named Contact from the Page Attributes box on the Edit Page screen,